# Invalid or corrupt jarFile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

This question has been asked various times across this forum but none of these seem to be stemming from the same issue I'm having. So here is my issue...

I have multiple runnable jar files I use for various projects, these are Selenium projects if that makes more sense. I've not had any issues with any of these jars in the past and I have two servers running all the jars. I am able to run the other jars just fine so can't figure out what the issue is. Only thing that is new is I added some new dependencies in this specific project. On two of my machines this jar works fine. I stored the jar on the network and ran it from these two machines - works fine. Run it from the server machine and I get "Invalid of corrupt jarFile xxx.jar". Since this error is so generic I have no idea what to go on...

Run the jar by using "java -jar xxx.jar [params]".

I did notice that the java version on my two machines is 1.8 and the server is 1.7 however the project is built on java 1.7.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Sugestion: Use a **checksum** (md5, sha2, etc) to ensure that your jar was successfully transfered between your 2 machines and the server.

Comment: Checksum matches I thought about that as well before but didn't check.

Comment: Try running your jar with classpath flag. Like `java -cp xxx.jar YourMainClass`

Comment: That worked... does that narrow down where the issue could be from?

Comment: Sounds like it's an issue with your MANIFEST.MF file, can you post it?

Comment: Here you go... http://pastebin.com/2CQwgjXz

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This comment isn't helpful. In this case it is not a code question but a running a jar problem. Adding an entire code library would not help out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a comment for you but I don't have the reputation to comment yet so here goes:

The java version is very possibly an issue. I know that I have had some serious issues very much like what you are explaining because I was using 1.8 (while the project was a 1.6 or 1.7). So using 1.7 instead of 1.8 could definitely be an issue.

I know this doesn't answer your question completely but if possible I would try upgrading your server (probably not an option I know).

Comment: I didn't feel like wasting more time troubleshooting this. I just decided to shoot for the upgrade and it worked. I have no idea why this was happening. Shouldn't be the solution but it works for me!